# Flush data to DB while processing concurrently

Tags: java, concurrency

I have 8 threads concurrently putting data into an ArrayBlockingQueue, the code for each thread looks like this:

```
import java.util.List;

public class PairProcessor implements Runnable {

private TagProcess tagProcess;

public PairProcessor(TagProcess tagProcess) {
    this.tagProcess = tagProcess;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    List<String[]> twoRow;
    while (true) {

        twoRow = tagProcess.getNext();

        if (twoRow == null)
            break;

        tagProcess.getAutotagResult().addAll(twoRow);

        if(tagProcess.getAutotagResult().size() >= 100) {
            System.out.println(tagProcess.getAutotagResult().size());
            tagProcess.getAutotagResult().clear();
        }
    }


    System.out.println("done");
}

}
```

Now I want to flush data in the ArrayBlockingQueue, when every its size reaches a certain threshold, for example 100. The ArrayBlockingQueue returned by:

```
tagProcess.getAutotagResult()
```

Can I get the first thread that meets this if, block the rest 7 threads, let this thread flush data (or do what ever it want) and then resume other threads.

Comment: Yes you can. Just to suggest alternatives, wouldn't it be better yet if the first threads that meets the condition spawns a NEW one whose job would be to drain the X(=100?) first elements, without blocking the other processors anymore than the "draining" needs (e.g. rely on your queue's performance caracteristics, not on an exclusive lock that will block everybody as you mention) ? It might or might not be suitable, but it seems reasonnable to ask.

Comment: would you mind giving me an example (in code)? For the suggest, it's really nice, but we will lose the order of the elements. Plus I already run with 8 threads, adding more threads seems to cost much more.

Comment: how about implementing a custom blockingqueue that support a flush method?

Comment: @mooc : blocking all your 8 threads waiting for the flush to finish vs. adding a 9th thread that triggers only when needed seems like a no brainer... but of course one must measure performance, not guess it. Custom blocking queue ? Surely a bad idea (in the long run) : too hard to get it right and bug free. Concurrency is hard. If you are a very gifted programmer (and if your code is intended to be maintained by others as good as you) why not. If not... stick to the jdk's primitives.

Comment: @mm0c : added note : my suggestion would not entail any loss of order. But please not your sample code does not keep the order of elements either : `addAll` is not atomic in `ArrayBlockingQueue`. If two threads `addAll` at the same time, then, elements from both threads can be interleaved.

Comment: Thanks @GPI, I didn't know about that `addAll` pretty much, thank you for pointing it out. I'm currently reimplementing an algorithm for a tool, which need to support hundreds of thousands of rows (in a list). I want to flush the data because that way, we can support even millions of rows of data. But it seems both impractical and impossible now, because the only way that I can think of now is using a custom synchronized collection, but as you said, it's not a wise choice. So I'll have to think of another way.

Comment: have a look at producer/consumer patterns, they may be enough for you. e.g. if `addAll` fails you, maybe you need a `BlockingQueue<List<Element>>`. You then only need to `add`, which is atomic (although you still don't know which of your 8 producers will `add` first). Otherwise, have a look at actor patterns (e.g. Akka). Or start another question with your more global requirements, instead of a specific issue like here ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class PairProcessor implements Runnable {

private BlockingQueue<String[]> autotagResult;
private TagProcess tagProcess;
private CountDownLatch doneSignal;

public PairProcessor(TagProcess tagProcess) {
    this.autotagResult = tagProcess.getAutotagResult();
    this.doneSignal = tagProcess.getDoneSignal();
    this.tagProcess = tagProcess;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    List<String[]> twoRow;
    List<String[]> drainList;
    String name = "drainProcess";
    while (true) {

        twoRow = tagProcess.getNext();

        if (twoRow == null)
            break;

        autotagResult.addAll(twoRow);
        synchronized (name) {
            if (autotagResult.size() >= 100) {
                drainList = new ArrayList<>();
                autotagResult.drainTo(drainList, 100);
                System.out.println(drainList.size());
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("done");
    doneSignal.countDown();
}

}
```

Updated code, I still dont know if this code is efficient? Does it scale well? The `addAll` is just for testing purpose, because I want to make sure that the shared `ArrayBlockingQueue` has the same amount of data with the source `List`. The `doneSignal` is used to signal the main thread when 8 threads done their jobs.

Comment: Most of the code use provided "synchronizer" `CountDownLatch` and synchronized collections `ArrayBlockingQueue`, the only thing I can think of that can cause trouble is the `synchronized(name)`. This means that the first thread encounter this synchronized will be the one to flush the data out. What else could happen here?

Comment: You synchronize on a method local variable, name. None of your threads can share this instance. Which means you threads do not synchronize with each other at all. They take a lock, which no other thread look at. You have to share the name object between your threads to have an exclusive access.

Comment: Apart from that the question « will it scale » can only have partial answers because we do not kno of your constraints, we only know how you plan on solving them. But generally speaking, using synchronized on a big chance of code that is running for a presumably long time is the definition of « it will not scale ».

Comment: Thanks @GPI for the <<will it scale>> part, adding new threads to flush data will add even more complexity. For example, suppose that the producer threads produce too quickly, so even though we create the flush-thread one after the other, we might have multiple flush-threads saving at the same time, but the order of the output need to be retained. For now I'm just testing with the synchronized, it seems work, but << it will not scale>> most likely to be true, I'm running into a dead end.

Comment: It's impossible now, I've just found out a disadvantage of mondoDB, it sucks at updating. Because if you want to update, you have to retrieve the object first, which painfully returns the entire data that has been added before. You got the idea. Now I think this topic can end.